# Not able to set properties in JavaScript class

Tags: javascript, constructor, properties

I am simply setting properties in a class in JavaScript:

```
class BookingReports extends ReportsInterface{ 
    var categoryID;
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    init(CatID)
    {
        this.categoryID=CatID;            
    }
}
```

But JavaScript is not accepting variable at all and giving error "unexpected identifier".

[image]

I am not getting idea what is syntax error. Is it because of inheritance or `super` keyword? I even tried using binding with this whole declaration. But it is not working.

Comment: Define variables inside the constructor and try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var categoryID` is just out of place there. You don't declare variables at the `class` level; you declare variables within the constructor or methods.

In your case, you probably don't want to declare a variable at all; instead, create the property in your constructor:

```
class BookingReports extends ReportsInterface{ 
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.categoryID = /*...some default value...*/;
    }

    init(CatID)
    {
        this.categoryID=CatID;            
    }
}
```

---

Side note: Having an `init` method doesn't make much sense; that's what the constructor is for. So:

```
class BookingReports extends ReportsInterface { 
    constructor(catID) {
        super();
        this.categoryID = catID;
    }
}
```

---

At some point, the [class fields proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) will reach Stage 4, at which point you will be able to "declare" properties at the `class` level if you want to:

```
// Valid if/when the class fields proposal advances
class BookingReports extends ReportsInterface { 
    categoryID; // Declares the property
    constructor(catID) {
        super();
        this.categoryID = catID;
    }
}
```

If you're initializing the property in the constructor, there's not a lot of point to that; but it can be useful for telling the reader (and JavaScript engine) the standard "shape" of your object up-front rather than making them (and it) analyze the constructor's code.

Comment: yes . this is working . can I use multiple constructor in javascript ? i tried but it is giving error "A class may only have one constructor"

Comment: My end purpose is to create another instance of class on document.ready of same js file and use class method on controls event . how can i achieve that

Comment: @NeerajVerma - I believe I suggested this yesterday, but it's well-worth your time to read through [MDN's page on classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). There can be only one constructor, since JavaScript doesn't have overloading (instead, all constructors and methods can be called with any number of arguments of any type).